# How to access questions of an account deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, feature-request, specific-question, question-answer-ban, user-accounts

As I tried to evade a question ban by opening another account, my account was deleted. Nevertheless, the answers/comments I received on my posts were of vital importance (to me at least). I write the titles of the posts I make in the margins of my book, or in my notes, so I know the exact titles of my questions.

The title of one such question is, "What is the correct way to write dissociation reactions?". My notes also inform me that it had an answer from @KarstenTheis.

Although I have some memory of the contents of the answer(s) posted, I don't remember the details. Recently, I have found myself in great need of revisiting that post for remembrance of the key concepts presented by the esteemed answerers and commenters there. Is it possible for someone (me) to gain access to that post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible for someone (me) to gain access to that post?

In general, once a post is deleted, you will need 10,000 reputation to see it. Your account is not treated any differently from any other account in this regard.

However, I don't see why *not* to undelete the post. The only possible issue is that this sets a precedent and we get flooded with meta requests to undelete posts, but I'm sceptical of that happening. (But please don't take advantage of my goodwill and ask me to undelete another bunch of questions.) Fine, the question isn't that great, but we regularly retain much worse......

So, here it is: [What is the correct way to write dissociation reactions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159773/what-is-the-correct-way-to-write-dissociation-reactions)